# How can I use strikethrough in a Label or text in flex 3 ?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How can I use strikethrough in a Label or text in flex 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`TextGraphic`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/langref/mx/graphics/TextGraphic.html) from the [Flex Gumbo SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4/) ([Using the beta Gumbo SDK in Flex Builder 3](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/02/using-the-beta-gumbo-sdk-in-flex-builder-3/)).

[Source](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/10/24/creating-strikethrough-text-on-a-textgraphic-control-in-flex-gumbo/)

Answer (score 3):

I needed the same, and ended up simplifying the mediagreenhouse solution somewhat:

```
package
{
    import flash.text.TextLineMetrics;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.controls.Label;

use namespace mx_internal;

public class StrikeLabel extends Label
{

    public function StrikeLabel()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );

        if( textField )
        {
            var metrics : TextLineMetrics = textField.getLineMetrics( 0 );
            var y : int = ( metrics.ascent * 0.66 ) + 2;

            graphics.clear();
            graphics.lineStyle( 1, getStyle( "color" ), 1 );
            graphics.moveTo( 0, y );
            graphics.lineTo( metrics.width, y );
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This works great until the text is multi-line, then it only strikesthrough the top line.

Comment: I fixed it with this copy everything below and format it and you'll see what I'm doing: `copy below this`
var nLines:uint = super.mx_internal::getTextField().numLines; var yPos:int = 0; for(var i:int = 0; i<nLines;i++){var metrics:TextLineMetrics = super.getLineMetrics(i);var y:int = Number(metrics.ascent * .66)+2;
yPos += y; graphics.lineStyle( 1, getStyle( "color" ), 1 ); graphics.moveTo( 0, yPos );graphics.lineTo( metrics.width, yPos ); yPos -= y; yPos+=metrics.height;} copy that and format it and you'll see what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs, you might be able to subclass label, override the updateDisplayList, and just draw a line through the middle of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Flex 3 example here: http://flexsnippets.mediagreenhouse.com/?p=46